# Change UILabel on SelectedRow

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying to change the label color of the cell in a tableView that is selected.
I am trying to reach this with the following code:

```
TextLabel.HighlightedTextColor = UIColor.White;
```

Unfortunately this does not work and will keep his original color that I filled in from the StoryBoard.

I will provide a picture of the full code. The blue background color does work but the label color does not.

[image]

EDIT

I am trying to change the button state based on if a row is selected yes or no. When a row is selected I would like to show a button on the bottom (outside of the tableView) to be shown (isEnabled = true) when I have no rows selected I want it to be set to disabled (isEnabled = false. How can I handle this the best?

Currently I have the following logic but this will end up in a crash with error code: Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x100044e70)

When I select a row and deselect the same row the app wil crash.

Code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        let selectedCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
        selectedCell?.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 84.0 / 255, green: 199.0 / 255, blue: 252.0 / 255, alpha: 1)
        self.checkButtonAvailability()
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let selectedCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
        selectedCell?.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.darkGray
        self.checkButtonAvailability()
    }
    @IBAction func nextBtnPressed(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 50
    }

    func checkButtonAvailability() {
        if (self.tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows?.count)! > 0 {
            nextBtn.isEnabled = true
            nextBtn.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 84.0 / 255, green: 199.0 / 255, blue: 252.0 / 255, alpha: 1)
        } else {
            nextBtn.isEnabled = false
            nextBtn.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray
        }   
    }
```

Comment: Please do not post code as an image. Please copy and paste the actual code into your question. It makes it much easier to read and reference when answering.

Comment: It's about the TextLabel.HighlightedTextColor = UIColor.White

Comment: That doesn't change the fact that you should not post code as an image.

Comment: The image is just boiler plate stuff and is meant to make it more clearer for the others. They don't need it to fix my issue.

Comment: And once again, that doesn't change the fact that you should not post code as an image. Please, never post code as an image for any reason. It's hard to read and reference. And if it's not needed, then don't post it in any form.

Comment: Sure. Will keep an eye on that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subclass your `UITableViewCell` and set it there:

```
class YourTableViewCell: UITableViewCell
{

    @IBOutlet weak var myLabel: UILabel!

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        if(selected) {            
            self.myLabel.textColor = UIColor.white
        } else {
            self.myLabel.textColor = UIColor(red: 84.0/255.0, green: 199.0/255.0, 252.0/255.0)
        }
    }      
}
```

Then Your `cellForRow` method could look like this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = ... as! YourTableViewCell 

    ...
    /// you don't need to set the highlight color here. 
}
```

If you want to track the button availability, use **Bool** public variable like this (outside of methods):

```
var someRowSelected = false
```

Then implement some kind of a checking method:

```
func checkButtonAvailability() {
    if self.tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows?.count > 0 {
        myButton.isEnabled = true
    } else {
        myButton.isEnabled = false
    }   
}
```

Then in your `didSelectRow` and `didDeselectRow` delegate methods you could call that method:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
   self.checkButtonAvailability()
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
       self.checkButtonAvailability()
}
```

Comment: why does this actually not work in the standard function of didSelectRow at indexPath?

Comment: I suppose it is too late to do it in didSelectRow method, as the row has already been selected. But if you try to do it earlier, you could be succesful. Try to type your line into cellForRow (as .HighlightedTextColor property is just a definition, not a forcing of a label to change its style). I haven't tried this yet.

Comment: thank you sir. Now when I select a row I want a button to be available and when no row is selected I want it to be disabled. How can I handle this the best? Because I cant drag an outlet of the button the custom cell class ofcourse.

Comment: @GiorgioE When a row is selected I would like to show a button on the bottom (outside of the tableView) to be shown (isEnabled = true) when I have no rows selected I want it to be set to disabled (isEnabled = false. How can I handle this the best?

Comment: @KevinVugts I updated the answer. Try. But this is actually new question, please consider to create a new one. Good luck!

Comment: @pedrouan but what if I deselected the same row or have multiple rows and deselect all?

Comment: Well I didn't know you want to track also reversal action. Updated.

Comment: @pedrouan when I do this and click the same row selected and then deselected I get a Thread 1: EXC_BREAKOUTPOINT(code =1, subcode=0x100090e79)

Comment: I haven't tested it. Actually I'm not at the Xcode, typing from the phone. This is just an idea, how you can get the right result. That count method is really useful.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124919/discussion-between-kevin-vugts-and-pedrouan).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change label colour you should change:

```
selectedCell.textLabel?.HighlightedTextColor = UIColor.white
```

to:

```
selectedCell.textLabel.textColor = UIColor.white
```

That is because `HighlightedTextColor` does not change your label color.

> // the 'highlight' property is used by subclasses for such things as
>   pressed states. it's useful to make it part of the base class as a
>   user property

This is what `HighlightedTextColor` does.

Hope it will help you.